A few questions about Boltzmann brains
So I've been thinking about Boltzmann brains and there are some questions which I wasn't able to answer online:
Given that Boltzmann brains only last for a split second, is experience (the notion or sensation of existing) for more than that duration proof that you're not a Boltzmann brain? In other words, is experience stored in memory in the same way that it is lived?
Should the memories in Boltzmann brains be self-consistent as logic and common sense fully arise from those memories or should they just be a mix of nonsensical and unrelated pieces of information?
Finally, what would be more likely: intelligent life arising on a planet or a boltzmann brain being generated?

I've always been under the impression that the "Boltzmann brain," as the idea that a disembodied momentary solipsist delusion has less entropy than an entire universe and must therefore be more probable than an actual universe with actual self-aware life, is an indication of a problem with the way we understand entropy and fluctuations rather than being an actual prediction. Getting into the weeds about details seems like a modern equivalent of medieval scholars debating how many angels could dance on a pinhead.

well, we have observational evidence for intelligent life, while boltzmann brains are basically an ad absurdum argument. i think it is clear which one seems more likely.

as it stands, this is basically the same question as "is reality an illusion". these questions are better left to philosophers.

I know it's an absurd thought experiment, but I mainly wanted to know if experiencing the present for more than a split second disproves that you're a Boltzmann brain...

What about Boltzmann kidneys? They could be very useful for transplants. Boltzmann livers too. What are the chances of one spontaneously forming during surgery?


Given that Boltzmann brains only last for a split second, is experience (the notion or sensation of existing) for more than that duration proof that you're not a Boltzmann brain ?

How do you define experience that lasts for more than a split second ? Any experience that is based solely on current perception can only last for a fraction of  second. Any experience that relies on the recall of memory is automatically suspect in the Boltzmann brain scenario.

Is experience stored in memory in the same way that it is lived ?

No. There is a very clear distinction between a here-and-now experience and the recollection of that experience from memory. Life would be very confusing if we could not distinguish between present experiences and memories.

Should the memories in Boltzmann brains be self-consistent ?

Yes. The whole point of the thought experiment is that pseudo-memories in a Boltzmann brain should be indistinguishable from "real" memories.

What would be more likely: intelligent life arising on a planet or a Boltzmann brain being generated ?

If we trust what our senses tell us about the make up and age of the universe, then the former is more likely. But that is a circular argument. In the Boltzmann brain scenario we cannot trust either our senses or our memories.
The Boltzmann brain scenario is an extreme form of solipsism and as such is not falsifiable.

But would you actually be able to know whether your experience came from memory or not?

@Flamethrower I think the difference between an experience and a memory of that experience is very clear. When you remember stubbing your toe you do not say ouch. When you remember a sunny day you do not start sweating. When you remember a scary moment from a movie you do not jump. Life would be very confusing if we could not distinguish between here-and-now experience and memories.

So experience alone is enough proof of not being a Boltzmann brain? And that would, in theory, kind of disprove the whole theory as they're predicted to be overwhelmingly more abundant than living things, right?

@Flamethrower That's not what I said. In the Boltzmann brain scenario your senses are just as unreliable as your memories. Your experiences are false (i.e. you are not experiencing the real universe), but they do not come from false memories.

No, experience is not a proof of anything, because you can't actually tell that the sense of that experience is a real memory or just a memory planted into your instantaneous brain.
This is similar to the argument by Young Earth Creationists that fossils and geologic evidence were created de novo by God to fool scientists into thinking that Earth is billions of years old. If God is omnipotent and perfect, there would be no way to distinguish this planted evidence from the real thing.


Given that Boltzmann brains only last for a split second, is experience (the notion or sensation of existing) for more than that duration proof that you're not a Boltzmann brain? In other words, is experience stored in memory in the same way that it is lived?

I would say the answer is certainly no... because at any given time it's possible that all accessible memories and knowledge have only just popped into existence in the previous instant. In other words there's no way to determine the duration of experience. We always live in the instant that is "now", which according to psychologists lasts from a a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds in perceptual terms.
I also wanted to expand on the nature of a Boltzmann brain itself. The whole concept arises from the idea that if we live in an infinite universe (or, multiverse, depending on how you define the term) that lasts for an infinite period of time, then by definition anything that is allowed by the laws of physics will eventually occur. If you have a cube with a trillion particles inside, there is a non-zero probability you will observe them all clustered into one corner even if the chance of that is vanishingly small. The idea is that due to random quantum fluctuations a living brain could materialize in the void.
A Boltzmann brain has traditionally been defined as an actual human brain, but I would surmise that with zero blood pressure, or the instant loss of blood pressure, that there would be no time for any internal experience to occur, not even a single thought, before unconsciousness and death. But this wouldn't rule out some other hardier biological manifestation, or more likely some virtual equivalent -- such as perhaps energy fields mimicking human consciousness or an actual memory chip accidentally running a simulation of human experience.

Should the memories in Boltzmann brains be self-consistent as logic and common sense fully arise from those memories or should they just be a mix of nonsensical and unrelated pieces of information?

I think the answer is no -- the appearance of a Boltzmann brain would happen completely at random, so it seems that it's equally as likely (and even more likely), that the brain would be psychotic, deranged, and lacking any internal consistency with a total jumble of meaningless memories. There's no guiding hand here. You do run into difficulties with what is known as the measurement problem when dealing with infinities, but if such brains exist and you took a random sample of them, it seems as if the ones with more order and that are internally self-consistent by accident would be far less likely than those that are put together in countless other random ways.

Finally, what would be more likely: intelligent life arising on a planet or a boltzmann brain being generated?

The first. Best guess is that the universe is 13.8 billion years old, give or take. The odds of a Boltzmann brain appearing is so vanishingly small (based on the chance of such a large collection of particles randomly appearing) that it would almost certainly not have occurred in the history of the universe, and would almost certainly not occur even when the universe is many, many orders of magnitude older. The amount of time needed is actually mind boggling, but infinity is literally forever. Which also implies an infinite number of Boltzmann brains. Remember that because of the infinities and random chance there is also probability associated with our entire planet or even the whole galaxy popping into existence, although the odds of that are even more vanishingly small.

The universe is only 13.8 billion years old in the mind of the Boltzmann brain. In reality it is infinitely old , but the brain does not know that. It imagined it read an imaginary paper by an imaginary scientist, that the universe is 13.8 billion years old.

Yes, good point! If we are indeed Boltzmann brains (or simulations) then all of our knowledge and everything we think we know about the universe could be false. We may be living in the far future! It becomes kind of circular though, because the possibility of the existence of Boltzmann brains depends in part on our understanding of quantum mechanics and the nature of probability. In any case, one must proceed according to what seems most likely.

Boltzmann brains are based on the premise that in an infinitude of possibilities, then anything that can happen will happen somewhere, sometime. In this infinitude of possibilities it just as possible a long lasting brain with built in life support system could be spontaneously created so there is no particular reason why such a brain should be short lived. If memories are encoded in the brain, then it just as possible that the brain comes preloaded with memories, which is as plausible as an infinitude of a monkeys with typewriters, accidently typing the complete works of Shakespeare letter for letter.
If a Boltzmann brain is an actual physical entity, it will require a universe with physical laws that allow matter to spontaneously form and so it is quite probable other matter will form and evolve into something living, so the presence of a Boltzmann brain does not necessarily exclude real living thinking organisms. In fact, under the premise that, "anything that can happen, will happen", real sentient life forms evolving cannot be excluded, as they are one of the possibilities.
In a comedy sketch about a funding panel discussing financing a moon landing, the possibility of faking the landing to save money was raised. After realising they would actually have to build a rocket and launch it, because people would want to see it and considering the cost of making a very good Hollywood fake of the Moon landing itself, they concluded that it would be cheaper to actually land on the Moon. Moral of the story: Faking it convincingly, does not always require less resources or probability than reality
